# am having this error but i cant find the error

Tags: c#

i am having this error when running my application:

> The name "DHR32S" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions
>   are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables.
>   Column names are not permitted.

here is my code:

```
c2.command("insert into haraki_item values(" + iddd + ",'Selling Facture','" + itemid + "','" + name + "'," + lasttotal + "," + balancee + ",'" + date + "')");
```

"DHR32S" is the itemid

Comment: chances are your item contains something you dont expect such as a number with a comma in?  this is why you should use parameters - let alone the whole sql injection reasons

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 1):

You SHOULD always use parameters, for lot of reasons. Here you are missing quotes around concatenated values.

```
 values(" + iddd + ", //<--you are missing quotes around idd
```

Try with parameters:

```
c2.command("insert into haraki_item values(@iddd ,@SellingFacture,@itemid ...
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@iddd,iddd);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(@SellingFacture,SellingFacture);
....
```

Comment: the iddd is int values not string so i must not use quotes for it

Comment: Either way, the second code block is what you should be doing (i.e. using `Parameters`).